# Weird MOT current measuerements

Tags: current, transformer, ohms-law

I have MOT transformer, which I want to use for DIY spot welder. I measured 0.85V on one turn of primary open circuit, it means cca 2.55V on three turns etc. This seems ok. What I do not however understand is the short-circuit current measured with my clamp meter. It just doesn't make sense to me. On one turn there is about 100A, on two turns 200A and on three turns of secondary about 300A of current flowing. But current in transformer should be directly opposed with the raising voltage, doesnt it? Can anyone explain to me why with more turns (and higher voltage) of secondary, the short-circuit current is also higher?

Comment: twice the voltage, twice the current. three times the voltage, three times the current. Something about the numeric progression....
FYI MOT is a 'microwave oven transformer' - I had to look it up.

Comment: 3x turns will deliver 1/3 the current ... for rated power into 9x the secondary circuit impedance. If you wound 3 turns with the same length of wire you have the same impedance.

Comment: You were probably told that a transformer trades current for voltage, but you are getting the different currents and voltages mixed up. The primary current is lower than the secondary current, and the primary voltage is higher than the secondary voltage, so it trades voltage for current when you go from primary to secondary, yes. But I bet you're thinking that has something to do with the voltage and current on two different transformers, and it doesn't. Adding extra turns doesn't trade current for voltage.